# Add a flag that meet certain conditions in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

For each subject, if either Cmax or AUC is zero, then FLAG should be 0. If both are 1 then FLAG=1.

```
SUB    METRIC    BE    FLAG
 1      Cmax     0       NA
 1      AUC      1       NA
 2      Cmax     1       NA
 2      AUC      1       NA
 3      Cmax     1       NA
 3      AUC      1       NA
 4      Cmax     1       NA
 4      AUC      0       NA
```

output should be this:

```
SUB    METRIC    BE     FLAG
 1      Cmax     0       0
 1      AUC      1       0
 2      Cmax     1       1
 2      AUC      1       1
 3      Cmax     1       1
 3      AUC      1       1
 4      Cmax     1       0
 4      AUC      0       0
```

Then I want to take the sum of FLAG but FLAG=1 for unique subject should be added once because it is the same subject. so, the sum for FLAG in the above should be equal to 2 not 4. I am using RStudio.

Comment: If there are going to be only two rows per `SUB`, then with base R we can do : `as.numeric(ave(df$BE, df$SUB, FUN= sum) == 2)` and to get the other part of your answer directly `sum(aggregate(BE~SUB, df, sum)[2] == 2)`

Answer (score 3):

We can use a logical condition after grouping by 'SUB'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(SUB) %>% 
  mutate(FLAG = as.integer(all(BE[METRIC %in% c("Cmax", "AUC")]==1)))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   SUB [4]
#    SUB METRIC    BE  FLAG
#  <int>  <chr> <int> <int>
#1     1   Cmax     0     0
#2     1    AUC     1     0
#3     2   Cmax     1     1
#4     2    AUC     1     1
#5     3   Cmax     1     1
#6     3    AUC     1     1
#7     4   Cmax     1     0
#8     4    AUC     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think akruns answer is more elegant, but here is my approach using dplyrs `case_when()`:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(SUB) %>% 
  mutate(
    FLAG = case_when(
      sum(BE) < length(BE)  ~ 0,
      sum(BE) == length(BE) ~ 1
    ))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   SUB [4]
#    SUB METRIC    BE  FLAG
#  <dbl>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   Cmax     0     0
#2     1    AUC     1     0
#3     2   Cmax     1     1
#4     2    AUC     1     1
#5     3   Cmax     1     1
#6     3    AUC     1     1
#7     4   Cmax     1     0
#8     4    AUC     0     0
```

Then you can make use of the `summarise()` functions to take to maximum of `FLAG`, and sum the `SUB_FLAG`. The sum of `SUB_FLAG` then is 2.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(SUB) %>% 
  mutate(
    FLAG = case_when(
      sum(BE) < length(BE)  ~ 0,
      sum(BE) == length(BE) ~ 1
      )
  ) %>%
  summarise(SUB_FLAG = max(FLAG)) %>% 
  summarise_at("SUB_FLAG", sum)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  SUB_FLAG
#      <dbl>
#1        2
```